# Setting up a 3d print character in multiple poses issue

Tags: 3d-printing, sculpt

Hey there I’m going back to basics on this simple character.

[image]

It will need to be 3d printed with multiple models in different poses.

In another post others said to sculpt it low poly first in it’s pose then remesh with more geometry and sculpt the fur, but if there’s 30 models to do then that means sculpting the fur 30 times which seems inefficient.

But if I remesh this base model first and sculpt the fur I have issues with posing the model.

Is there a better way to get these 30 models done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, sorry but I didn't get what exactly is the problem, posing your model or adding fur to it ?

Comment: Can't you rig the low-poly version with an armature, then add a Multi-Res modifier to sculpt the fur, and finally do 30 poses? I guess you have to apply the MR modifier before you do the 3D print.